# How to assign data validation to prompt message box

Tags: validation, user-interface

How do I get data validation on the input either from a sheet with selected numbers or between a selected range?

I also am looking to restrict access to this page if they do not enter valid information. This is what I have so far.

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var result = ui.prompt(
    'Name v3.3 Access',
    'Enter employee ID Number',
    ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL
  );

  // Process the user's response.
  var button = result.getSelectedButton();
  var text = result.getResponseText();
  if (button == ui.Button.OK) {
    // User clicked "OK".
    ui.alert('Your employee ID number is ' + text + '.');
  } else if (button == ui.Button.CANCEL) {
    // User clicked "Cancel".
    ui.alert('You did not enter your ID Number');
  } else if (button == ui.Button.CLOSE) {
    // User clicked X in the title bar.
    ui.alert('You closed the dialog.');
  }
}
```

Comment: You should indicate the programming language you're using.

Comment: it's google apps script

Comment: Yes, it is google scripting, which is technically java script to a certain degree.